# Want the count how many times row changes from -1 to 1 or vice-versa in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

SQL query to display the count, how many times row changes from -1 to 1 or vice-versa in SQL Server in a table.

Let the table name be `A`

```
col1
-----
1
-1
-1
1
1
-1
```

Comment: What defines the order of your data? If you have no way of ordering your data, with an `ORDER BY`, to maintain the order you show in your question, the answer is "you can't".

Comment: not getting the question.

Comment: I don't really know how to clarify my question more... *"What defines the order of your data?"* is pretty clear. When you write your `SELECT` statements, what is the `ORDER BY` clause you use to guarantee you get the data in the order it is above? Obviously it isn't `ORDER BY col1`, and that would put all the rows with `-1` first, and all the ones with `1` last, so what column *can* you order your data by?

Comment: oo, okay got it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this question to have an answer, you need a column that specifies the ordering.  SQL tables represent *unordered* (multi)sets.  There is no inherent ordering.  To answer your question, you can use `lag()` and conditional aggregation:

```
select sum(case when col1 = -1 and prev_col1 = 1 then 1 else 0
           end) as change_minus_to_plus,
       sum(case when col1 = 1 and prev_col1 = -1 then 1 else 0
           end) as change_plus_to_minus
from (select t.*,
             lag(col1) over (order by <ordering col<) as prev_col1
      from t
     ) t
```

Answer (score -1):

```
select count(*) from (
 select case when col1 <> lag(col1,1,col1) over (order by id) then 1 end rn
from table 
) t
```